# Oracle. Не выполняется запрос

Tags: база-данных, oracle, запрос

Запрос: составьте список всех сотрудников, зарабатывающих больше среднего оклада по отделу, в котором они работают

Вывожу среднюю зарплату по отделам:

```
SELECT AVG(salary) 
FROM listworker, listdep
WHERE listworker.department_code = listdep.code_department
GROUP BY (listdep.name_department)
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я использую подзапрос:

```
SELECT worker_surname, name_department, salary
FROM listworker, listdep
WHERE listworker.salary > 
      (SELECT AVG(salary) 
       FROM listworker, listdep
       WHERE listworker.department_code = listdep.code_department
       GROUP BY (listdep.name_department));
```

Но он возвращает больше одного значения, как сделать, чтобы сравнивал среднюю зарплату только со своим отделом.

знаю, что можно указать дополнительно условие, но так не работает т.к. тут работа идет только с агрономией, а с другими отделами нет

```
SELECT worker_surname, name_department, salary
FROM listworker, listdep
WHERE listworker.salary > 
     (SELECT AVG(salary) 
      FROM listworker, listdep
      WHERE listworker.department_code = listdep.code_department 
        AND listdep.name_department = 'Агрономия'
      GROUP BY (listdep.name_department));
```

Comment: Вы хотите сравнивать зарплату со средней зарплатой в том же отделе или со средней по всем отделам?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше воспользоваться оконными функциями, которые позволяют получить группированные данные одновременно с исходными:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT listworker.*,
           avg(salary) over(parition by listdep.name_department) avg_salary
      FROM listworker, listdep
     WHERE listworker.department_code = listdep.code_department
  ) X
 WHERE salary > avg_salary
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, а как сделать так, чтобы он еще и название отдела выводил ?

Comment: @Alexander В подзапросе в список выбираемых значений добавьте это поле